# CustomScript extension - Cannot run bash script on Azure CentOS VM

Tags: linux, bash, azure, virtual-machine

New to Azure (and Linux)...

CentOS 7.2 VM.

I configure a new Azure CentOS VM, and set the following for "Custom Script for Linux" extension:
Script files: bob.sh (Selected from local workstation)
Command: sh bob.sh

bob.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "This is a test" > test.txt

# Update instance packages
sudo yum -y check-update

# Download and install Node.js
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

After VM deploys, I get a "Deployment Failed" error on the dashboard.

The error/status message, displayed to me in JSON because Azure thinks I am a computer, is:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptForLinux'. Error message: \"Malformed status file (000003)Invalid status/status: failed\"."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Malformed status file (000003)Invalid status/status: failed??

Mr. DuckDuckGo seems to have no information on this error.

I SSH into the VM:

File test.txt does not exist.

I attempted to view log files on the VM at /var/log/azure/custom-script/handler.log, but I don't have permission.

I can manually run each step in the script successfully.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

waagent.log (Last 30 lines)

```
2017/03/15 18:59:08.306400 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 error state: Last Failure: 0.0, Total Failures: 0, Fatal: False
2017/03/15 18:59:08.318722 INFO Ensuring Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 is downloaded
2017/03/15 18:59:08.326959 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 was previously downloaded - skipping download
2017/03/15 18:59:08.337453 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 loaded manifest from /var/lib/waagent/WALinuxAgent-2.2.5/HandlerManifest.json
2017/03/15 18:59:08.351363 INFO Wire server endpoint:168.63.129.16
2017/03/15 18:59:08.392832 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Expected handler state: enabled
2017/03/15 18:59:08.405362 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Current handler state is: NotInstalled
2017/03/15 18:59:08.418354 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Download extension package
2017/03/15 18:59:08.451541 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Unpack extension package
2017/03/15 18:59:08.484619 INFO Event: name=Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux, op=Download, message=Download succeeded
2017/03/15 18:59:08.505998 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Initialize extension directory
2017/03/15 18:59:08.522399 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Update settings file: 0.settings
2017/03/15 18:59:08.538153 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Install extension.
2017/03/15 18:59:08.553039 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Launch command:customscript.py -install
2017/03/15 18:59:08 CustomScriptForLinux started to handle.
2017/03/15 18:59:08 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] cwd is /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1
2017/03/15 18:59:08 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Change log file to /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log
2017/03/15 18:59:09.573891 INFO Event: name=Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux, op=Install, message=Launch command succeeded: customscript.py -install
2017/03/15 18:59:09.591446 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Enable extension.
2017/03/15 18:59:09.602945 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Launch command:customscript.py -enable
2017/03/15 18:59:09 CustomScriptForLinux started to handle.
2017/03/15 18:59:09 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] cwd is /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1
2017/03/15 18:59:09 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Change log file to /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log
2017/03/15 18:59:09 CustomScriptForLinux started to handle.
2017/03/15 18:59:09 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] cwd is /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1
2017/03/15 18:59:09 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Change log file to /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log
2017/03/15 18:59:10.628480 INFO Event: name=Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux, op=Enable, message=Launch command succeeded: customscript.py -enable
2017/03/15 18:59:10.815782 INFO Event: name=WALinuxAgent, op=HealthCheck, message=Blob type match [PageBlob]
2017/03/15 19:14:05.254971 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 launched with command 'python -u bin/WALinuxAgent-2.2.5-py2.7.egg -run-exthandlers' is successfully running
2017/03/15 19:14:05.273919 INFO Event: name=WALinuxAgent, op=Enable, message=Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 launched with command 'python -u bin/WALinuxAgent-2.2.5-py2.7.egg -run-exthandlers' is successfully running

handler.log:
No such file or directory
```

Comment: `sudo su; cat /var/log/waagent.log; cat /var/log/azure/custom-script/handler.log` and post it here

Comment: what does `selected from local workstation` mean? You expect that file to be magically available on the VM you provisioned? It won't be, you have to download it to the VM first

Comment: Yeah, I expected the file to be magically available since I am coming from an AWS background i.e. UserData.    What is the best course of action for having a VM automatically self-provision using data/files from Azure Blob storage without having to manually push a file to an existing VM.

Comment: @programmerj You had better check log `/var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I use your script and test in my lab. I get same error log. I check log in `/var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux‌​/1.5.2.1/extension.l‌​og`. I find some `sudo` error.

**Please remove `sudo` in your script. Azure executes the script as root user.** After remove `sudo`, you could install extension successfuly.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a test" > test.txt

# Update instance packages
yum -y check-update

# Download and install Node.js
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted; this is the correct answer.  I removed "sudo" from all of my script entries and now it works.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

For the file to be available on the VM, just upload it somewhere publicly available and issue a command to download it. See this [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json)

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extensionName'))]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
    "type": "CustomScript",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": "[split(parameters('fileUris'), ' ')]", ## << file url goes here
      "commandToExecute": "[parameters('commandToExecute')]"
    },
    "protectedSettings": { ## << these are needed if you are using Azure Blob which is not publicly accessible
      "storageAccountName": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountName')]",
      "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountKey')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A script can just be uploaded from your workstation to the portal, the script will then be executed when the VM is provisioned.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/

section: Deploy the CustomScript Extension through Azure Portal

Comment: Yeah...its the second step.  I just first want to ensure I can get a VM to pull down and successfully execute a script.

Comment: you cant automate portal actions, obviously, my answer deals with that

Comment: correct, i understand that.  thanks for you answer, i will certainly use it as a reference when i begin researching automation.